# Create a logic based column in R data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I'm attempting to create a loop/function or whatever will work that will go row by row in my df and give me a new column based on the values of two other columns.

For example, the data frame looks like the below:

```
V1 <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B')
V2 <- c('X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z')
df <- data.frame(V1,V2)
df

V1  V2
A   X           
A   X           
A   Y           
B   Y           
B   Z           
B   Z
```

And the logic behind the third, calculated column is as follows:

```
if V1 = A & V2 = X, then V3 = r
if V1 = B & V2 = X, then V3 = t
if V1 = A & V2 = Y, then V3 = n
if V1 = B & V2 = Y, then V3 = n
if V1 = A & V2 = Z, then V3 = x
if V1 = A & V2 = Z, then V3 = x
```

This would result in the data frame looking something like this:

```
V1  V2  V3
A   X   r       
A   X   t       
A   Y   n       
B   Y   n       
B   Z   x       
B   Z   x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid `ifelse()` you can try this. Also, check your final output.

```
#Conditions
c1 <- df$V1 == 'A' & df$V2 == 'X'
c2 <- df$V1 == 'B' & df$V2 == 'X'
c3 <- df$V1 == 'A' & df$V2 == 'Y'
c4 <- df$V1 == 'B' & df$V2 == 'Y'
c5 <- df$V1 == 'A' & df$V2 == 'Z'
c6 <- df$V1 == 'A' & df$V2 == 'Z'

#Create variable

df$V3 <- NA

#Assign

df$V3[c1] <- 'r'
df$V3[c2] <- 't'
df$V3[c3] <- 'n'
df$V3[c4] <- 'n'
df$V3[c5] <- 'x'
df$V3[c6] <- 'x'
```